# Print node text and tags from XML to CSV file

Tags: xml, python-2.7, csv

```xml
<devices>

  <entry name="Rule 1">
    <from>
      <member>abcd</member>
    </from>
    <to>
      <member>efg</member>
    </to>
  </entry>

  <entry name="Rule 2">
    <from>
      <member>lmno</member>
    </from>
    <to>
      <member>hijk</member>
    </to>
  </entry>
</devices>
```

**This is what I applied to find Node Tags and Text **

```
def policy():
    with open('G:\XML-1.xml', 'rt') as f:
        tree = ET.parse(f)

    for node0 in tree.findall('.//devices//rules/entry'):
        d1 = {'rule': node0.get('name')}
        print d1
    for node1 in tree.findall('.//devices/from/member'):
        d2 = {'from': node1.text}
        print d2
    for node2 in tree.findall('.//devices//to/member'):
        d3 = {'to': node2.text}
        print d3
policy()
```

**This is Result after running code**

```
{'rule':Rule1}
{'rule':Rule2}
{'from':abcd}
{'from':lmno}
{'to':efg}
{'to':hijk}
```

1. Add a condition to look for more rules in entry name.
2. If rule added,search similar tags and text.
3. print in csv file by combining values by Rule 1, Rule 2 like this

   Rule1
   abcd
   efg
   Rule2
   lmno
   hijk

Comment: I couldn't find any question in this 'question'... what is your question specifically?

Comment: @har07    how to print in CSV file with values from each Rule For eg Rule1 abcd efg, Rule 2 lmno hijk